# Java sometime return empty string when reading file

Tags: java, file, java-10

This is weird but I don't know why it being caused.

I'm using Java 10 and trying to read a file. Sometime the file is read and the file's content is outputted to the console however sometimes it doesn't output the content at all.

I've confirmed that it can read and write the file and something is in the string variable I use but whatever it returns it prevent anything from being printed to the console sometimes.

It sometimes works the first few times then fails the next ten. All the other code is working as expected except when it interacts with this hidden variable. No exception is thrown from it.

Here is the code to test with.

```
public String getText(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        System.out.println(file.canRead());

        String text = null;
        System.out.println("try getting file content");

        try {
            byte[] array =Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            System.out.println(""+array.length);
            text = new String(array,  StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        if(text != null) {
            System.out.println("file content have been retrieved successfully");
            System.out.println("["+text+"]"); //this line won't print sometimes
        }

        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` **always** (until you learn proper logging). Otherwise you won't know what's going wrong.

Comment: what is the output you get in the failed scenario?

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo The system.out.print won't print anything not even the '[]'

Comment: But, the line above it is printed?

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo yep weird right?

Comment: That is indeed weird. May be better if you share the exact file and the output in the question.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo I would but it has confidential data in however I will try with a different file to see if the file is the issue

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo the issue was with the file itself. Maybe a strange character caused it. Thank you for you help. Can you please post it as an answer so I can mark your solution as correct

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott good! I doubt there is enough ground for an answer here :) . Cheers!

Comment: Mad suggestion but it happened me before. Try highlighting where the text was suppose to print. Copy and paste it into a notepad. 

I had an issue before where I thought it wasn't printing but it was just printing the same colour as the console and I couldn't see it.

Comment: @DeaneKane yes that could be one reason. It is a good idea to copy paste it and check it again in notepad.